# Manipulate individual CSS transform effects with jquery

Tags: javascript, css

If my elements have multiple CSS tranform effects defined, like so:

```
transform: translate(400px, 40px) scale(1);
```

But I want to manipulate only one of them, such as changing its translate coordinates without affecting the current value of scale, can I do that with JQuery in a way that won't force me to parse the whole string?

Something similar can already be done with the "class" attribute - I can use hasClass, addClass, removeClass and JQuery will do the parsing for me.

Can I do something similar with the transform CSS pProperty?

Comment: maybe you prefer to move the "static" transformation into a class and then modify freely the entire transform with `.css('transform', '')`

Comment: Yes kpull, that is what I ended up doing - ideally I wanted to not store the "scale" value somewhere other than the DOM, but alas this was the most practical way.

Answer (score 1):

The better way to do that is mixing `CSS` and `JQuery`. I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RX47u/) that only use `CSS` and `JavaScript` there you can see that using classes it's enought.
I recommend to you do that with `JQuery` cause alow you to do more complex things.
Only `CSS` is not enought for a complex effect and only `JQuery` isn't efficient encoding.

HTML:

```
<div id="d1"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:red;
}

.scale{
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: scale(0.5);
}

.translate{
    -webkit-transform: translate(100px,0); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
     transform: translate(100px,0);
}

.scale.translate{
    -webkit-transform: translate(50px,0) scale(0.5); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
     transform: translate(50px,0) scale(0.5);
}
```

JS:

```
var d1 = document.getElementById("d1");
d1.setAttribute("class","scale");
setTimeout(function(){
    d1.setAttribute("class","translate");
},3000);
setTimeout(function(){
    d1.setAttribute("class","translate scale");
},6000);
```

Comment: Hi Xdevelop,
thanks for the idea but this is not quite I needed - the ability to parametrize the values of the CSS properties is of paramount importance, and having a set of pre-ordained values is just not gonna cut it, no matter how large.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using jQuery then you might as well use the considerable animation capabilities that come with jQuery by default, and forget about the css properties themselves.

That said, if you're hell bent on having control over the individual transform properties then your best bet is to use nested elements where each element has one transform rule applied:

```js
function translateDiv(){
  var translateDiv = document.getElementById('translate');
  if( translateDiv.classList.contains( 'translate' ) ){
    translateDiv.classList.remove( 'translate' );
  } else {
    translateDiv.classList.add( 'translate' );
  }
}

function rotateDiv(){
  var rotateDiv = document.getElementById('rotate');
  if( rotateDiv.classList.contains( 'rotate' ) ){
    rotateDiv.classList.remove( 'rotate' );
  } else {
    rotateDiv.classList.add( 'rotate' );
  }
}

function scaleDiv(){
  var scaleDiv = document.getElementById('scale');
  if( scaleDiv.classList.contains( 'scale' ) ){
    scaleDiv.classList.remove( 'scale' );
  } else {
    scaleDiv.classList.add( 'scale' );
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #FBCE0C;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.scale {
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.translate {
  transform: translate(120px, 200px);
}

#btns {
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div id="btns">
  <button onclick='translateDiv()'>Translate</button>
  <button onclick='rotateDiv()'>Rotate</button>
  <button onclick='scaleDiv()'>Scale</button>
</div>

<div id="translate">
  <div id="rotate">
    <div id="scale">
      <div id="block">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```